# Paypal IPN beginner - not working at all

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

First off, I'm trying to create a premium content area on my website. I'm not entirely sure if this is the right way to go about this, but nevertheless I've been at this for several hours. I'm really trying to just write a script that sees if they paid. Hopefully some of you guys can help.

I'm using the generic code they supply, but it always comes up with the second area no matter what I do in the simulator. Any ideas?

```
   <?php

// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    $to = "chardd@adf.com";
$subject = "Complete";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
echo "Mail Sent.";

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation

        $to = "charding407@gmail.com";
$subject = "failed";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
echo "Mail Sent.";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're using the simulator (I guess you mean PayPal Sandbox), you need to call a different URL in curl_init(), being "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr". But your question is not too clear on what the actual problem is.

Comment: @markdwhite Thanks. I wasn't clear because I wasn't sure what the problem is. I fixed it now.. I'm not entirely sure how or why it works now, but when it works it works and you can't argue with that!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check IPN Troubleshooting Tips here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/

According to Troubleshooting Tips [markdwhite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817834/markdwhite) is right.

You should change this line:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
```

with this:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
```

Then i think the code will come up with the "First Area" of yours :)